# In Spring Boot how to migrate from CompositeHealthIndicator & HealthAggregator to CompositeHealthContributor & StatusAggregator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

In a Spring Boot 2.2 application I have created a [`CompositeHealthIndicator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthIndicator.html) combined with a [`HealthAggregator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.html) like this:

```
CompositeHealthIndicator healthIndicator(Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators){
    var aggregator = new OrderedHealthAggregator();
    aggregator.setStatusOrder(DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, CUSTOM_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, HYSTRIX_CIRCUIT_OPEN_STATUS, UP, UNKNOWN);
    return new CompositeHealthIndicator(aggregator, healthIndicators);
}
```

However, after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5, both classes are gone. `HealthAggregator` was replaced by [`StatusAggregator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/StatusAggregator.html) and `CompositeHealthIndicator` was replaced by [`CompositeHealthContributor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthContributor.html).

Unfortunately, a `CompositeHealthContributor` can't be created with a `StatusAggregator` like a `CompositeHealthIndicator` could be created with a `HealthAggregator`. There is no such constructor for it.

How can I combine `CompositeHealthContributor` with `StatusAggregator`?